# Get access to method on myclass into $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I created two methods on a Javascript class:

```
this.saveData = function(){
    var url_send = 'm1=1&m2=2'
    $.ajax({
        url: '/save.php',
        dataType : "text",
        data:url_send,
        type:'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            // this is does not correct
            this.showAcceptBox('error_msg_0');
        }
    });
};

this.showAcceptBox = function(msg_id){
    $('#error_box').removeClass('alert-negative');
    $('#error_box').html($('#'+msg_id).html());
    $('#error_box').show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#error_box').fadeOut('slow',function(){
            $('#error_box').addClass('alert-negative');
        });
    },this.message_box_timeout);
};
```

How do I correct the call method from my class into jQuery `.ajax()`?

Comment: `var url_send = 'm1=1&m2=2'` is missing a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to capture `this` in a closure:

```
this.saveData = function() {
    var url_send = { m1: 1, m2: 2 };
    var _self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/save.php',
        dataType : 'text',
        data: url_send,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            _self.showAcceptBox('error_msg_0');
        }
    });
};
```

or pass it as parameter using the `context` switch:

```
this.saveData = function() {
    var url_send = { m1: 1, m2: 2 };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/save.php',
        dataType : 'text',
        data: url_send,
        context: this,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            this.showAcceptBox('error_msg_0');
        }
    });
};
```

Quote from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **context**
>
> This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By
>   default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings
>   used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the settings passed to
>   $.ajax). For example specifying a DOM element as the context will make
>   that the context for the complete callback of a request, like so:
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>   url: "test.html",
>   context: document.body,
>   success: function(){
>     $(this).addClass("done");
>   }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

i don't see how you give your msg_id :

```
this.showAcceptBox = function(data){
    $('#error_box').removeClass('alert-negative');
    $('#error_box').html(data);
    $('#error_box').show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#error_box').fadeOut('slow',function(){
            $('#error_box').addClass('alert-negative');
        });
    },this.message_box_timeout);
};
```

Or you can retrieve whatever you want in your ajax answer like $('#msg_id',data). Everything depends on what your call is returning.

Comment: try adding some breakpoint with firebug and see if it has console errors and if you can enter the success method. Imo, you are just messing up context with "this" like said by previous post and your answer data is not correctly processed

Comment: I remove a lot code from examle methods. Sorry. But second does not necessary.